# SQL Do not return column if value is zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

This query returns one row with columns Ready, Processing, Complete, Failed and Error with totals for each.  Is there a way to rewrite this query so that columns that have a total of zero are not returned?

I'm using this to populate the mschart control and I don't wan't labels on the chart if there are 0 instances of that category.

```
SELECT        
              SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'R' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Ready,
              SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Processing, 
              SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Complete,
              SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Failed,
              SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'E' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Error
FROM  MailDefinition
```

Comment: Only if you have 5 UNIONs, each with HAVING. And then sort it out in the client code

Comment: @gbn -- what about dynamically creating the sql, and then executing it?

Comment: @kuru kuru na... : Dynamic SQL is a pain in the arse for security, manageability and troubleshooting.

Comment: @gbn -- true enough, and I've had several headaches to prove it, but...he's asking if it can be done in tsql...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is take what you have, throw it into an unpivot, then remove all of the 0 records.

```
select
    Type, 
    Sum
from
(
    SELECT                       
        SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'R' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Ready,               
        SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Processing,                
        SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Complete,               
        SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Failed,               
        SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'E' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Error 
FROM  MailDefinition 
) a
unpivot
(
     Sum for Type in ([Ready],[Processing],[Complete],[Failed],[Error])
) u
where Sum>0
```

That does, of course, entail changing your chart some.

Comment: yes thank you           .....need more characters.....to post this...annoying feature of comments....

Answer (score 5):

No, because the shape of the query (the fields it contains) has to be known. Only the data can change, and that is what you should be looking for. You can dynamically remove or hide labels based on `0` or `null` data in a column.

Comment: Since the reporting tool needs to know which fields it will have to work with so that it can bind them in the report / charts, you can't write a query using dynamic SQL in this case.

Comment: I thought there was an autogenerate columns feature in there...let me check on that.